# Run Windows command from flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Is it possible to delete the contents of a local XML file using a Flash CS5 document being played on the desktop and using AS3?

Ok i have done some research but still no luck. I was going to use a separate batch file with a windows command that did what I needed but since I will be calling the fscommand once a second the dos window would pop up a lot.

Are there any thirdy party plugins that will allow flash to run windows commands?

Comment: As has been noted in one of the answers, AIR is what you are looking for here. One of the major features of AIR is ability to access and work with the local file system. AIR allows you to make desktop apps and is more flexible than Zinc if you are doing something custom. Not knocking zinc, it's great at what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is read-only. It does not have access to create, delete, or otherwise modify files locally or on a server. The typical technique is to pass the heavy lifting onto to some tech that does, like php.

On the other hand, AIR does have access to all manner of functions like this, even to native processes. If you are looking to run an application only on a client machine, its a great alternative.

Comment: Is AIR built into flash cs5 or does it come with the CS5 Production Premium?

Comment: Air is a modified flash based platform, incorporating html, css and javascript as well. There are a number of methods developing air applications. Its an extensive topic, and you can easily find any number of tutorials on the googles. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [MDM Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/); its an alternative runtime for flash content which provides many additional features accessible via their own API, reffered to as [{mdm}Script](http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.